# Angularjs change date format in api response

Tags: angularjs

in Angularjs I got a response like this format in date **`created_at : "2018-02-21 00:00:00"`**

i want to change in to in this format **`21-Feb-2018`**

How to achive this ?

Comment: *"How to achive this ?"* by parsing `created_at` into Date object first then using built-in date filter.

Comment: Can you please give some example

Comment: Of course, here we go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to customize date format into controller, then try this way..

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
  var created_at = "2018-02-21 00:00:00";
  created_at = $filter('date')(new Date(created_at), "dd-MMM-yyyy");

  console.log(created_at)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the date filter in angular. Below is a demo of the same. More details for angular [Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [new Date('2018-02-21 00:00:00'),
  new Date('2018-02-22 00:00:00'),
  new Date('2018-02-23 00:00:00')
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

  <p ng-repeat="date in dates">Date = {{ date | date : "dd-MMM-yyyy" }}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: it's in ng-repeat get api how to apply there

Comment: same the same way i have done here. you might be having the date as an object property just apply this filter same as above it will work fine